# Class instances store different values than originally given

Tags: python, class, instance

I have a problem in my current project and i narrowed down the problem to this.

I want this output: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...

But my output: 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, ...

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, command):
        self.command = command


listOfFoos = []

for i in range(10):
    listOfFoos.append(Foo(command=(lambda: print(i))))

for foo in listOfFoos:
    foo.command()
```

Comment: Have a look at this https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: Lambdas have late binding. So the reference to `i` will refer to the last value of `i` in the loop which is 9.

Comment: N Chauhan how can i work around this?

Comment: `command=lambda x=i:print(x)`